# Sorting in Crosstab sort column/row group with Order by expression

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I know there is a similar thread here already, but that doesn't work for me.

Background: *Jaspersoft Studio 6*

I have a data set like this:

[image]

Created a crosstab like this on this dataset:

[image]

How to sort the column group to prod c, prod a, prod b instead of current?

I tried put this expression in Order by expression of the column group.

[image]

```
$F{product}.equals("prod c")? 1 : $F{product}.equals("prod a")? 2:3
```

But it says

[image]

edit: added source, this is the version without sorting and it runs fine without error but without sorting of course.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-06-08T14:14:48 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0a3345e5-7859-4366-9ccf-b215cf60a3b0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="vha"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'channel a' as "sales channel", 'prod a' as product, 1 as amount
union all select 'channel a' as salesChannel, 'prod b' as product, 1 as amount
union all select 'channel a' as salesChannel, 'prod c' as product, 1 as amount
union all select 'channel b' as salesChannel, 'prod a' as product, 1 as amount
union all select 'channel b' as salesChannel, 'prod b' as product, 1 as amount
union all select 'channel b' as salesChannel, 'prod c' as product, 1 as amount]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="sales channel" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="amount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="224" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="91" y="24" width="459" height="200" uuid="66af64fd-5d36-48a9-9356-f1c2cd55f6a0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <rowGroup name="sales channel1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{sales channel}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="27883596-a403-4b9a-a3d5-d18adced1ec1"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sales channel1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7e48fc9b-d619-4b04-8b50-4fbd6174509e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total sales channel1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="product1" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="81d54f8e-11ab-4841-9aef-ef224899c337"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{product1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0925adf9-e1d5-4b68-a7c5-0650b7e72721"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total product1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="amount_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="cdbc8bf6-e55f-4e69-9505-d40d01870add"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="product1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3543f652-7dee-43fd-84ba-514613b8ac03"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="sales channel1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9657bd6f-c862-4462-b88f-6ea0e049a3ad"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="sales channel1" columnTotalGroup="product1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8311db87-f185-447a-b692-ce878b7fdff5"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: @AlexK yes it works without sorting.

Comment: Updated, added source.

Comment: @tobi6 no, it's just a simple report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports crosstab sorting with comparatorExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314780/jasper-reports-crosstab-sorting-with-comparatorexpression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned @tobi6 in his post you can use *Measures* in *orderByExpression* (you can additionaly use *Buckets* with $V{} expression but it may be a hard way)

In your case the simplest way is to add new *Measure* with sorting rules.

```
<measure name="productForSort" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}.equals("prod b") ? 1 : $F{product}.equals("prod c") ? 2 : 3]]></measureExpression>
</measure>
```

After that you can use this *Measure* in *orderByExpression* expression:

```
<bucket class="java.lang.String">
    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></bucketExpression>
    <orderByExpression><![CDATA[$V{productForSort}]]></orderByExpression>
</bucket>
```

For my test *csv* datasource:

```
sales channel, product, amount
channel a, prod c, 5
channel a, prod a, 1
channel b, prod a, 3
channel a, prod b, 1
channel b, prod b, 1
```

the result was like this:

[image]

As you see the *"product b"* is going first.

---

*Notes*:

Question is similar (duplicates) a really great post [Jasper Reports crosstab sorting with comparatorExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314780/876298). You can find more information in this post.

My answer is similar as the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859287/876298) by @PetterFriberg. But in this case we can ommit the using of *Comparator*

Another two answers are also good, specially the R&D by @AndreasDietrich

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I have seen that post, but couldn't figure out how to do with the comparatorExpression. This post at least proves no comparatorExpression is needed.

Comment: FYI, in my case, the measure variable was not available in the GUI, so i had to add the line in the source code within my bucket class. Super easy, just didn't realize the measure variable wouldn't be accessible in GUI

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is a best way to edit *jrxml* via simple text editor

Answer (score 1):

When using the **Order By Expression**, no *Fields* `$F{}` can be accessed, only *measure variables* (from [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#orderByExpression)):

> The expression is evaluated in the context of the crosstab group and can reference measure variables, which evaluate to group totals.

**EDIT**

*Measure variables* are predefined when creating a crosstab. They follow a pattern (from [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v621/working-crosstabs), "Understanding Crosstab Total Variables"):

> When you have multiple row or column groups, you can use crosstab total variables to combine data at different aggregation levels (for example, to calculate a percentage). The following built-in variables are available:
>
> • `<Measure>_<Column Group>_ALL`: The total of all the entries in the specified column group and the current row.
>
> • `<Measure>_<Row Group>_ALL`: The total of all the entries in the specified row group and the current column.
>
> • `<Measure>_<Row Group>_<Column Group>_ALL`: The combined total of all the entries in the specified row and column groups.
>
> You can also select these variables from the expression editor for the Expression field on the Text Field tab of the Properties view for a measure.

So as far as I understand it, you can use those variables to group and order your results. Those variables show up in the expression editor for the crosstab (there is a screenshot in the source).

Comment: @AlexK it says: Field not found: product1

Comment: @tobi6 But what exactly I should do?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there's a buggy thing for me where i am unable (in Jasper Studio 6.4) to select Measures in the GUI from the Order By dropdown, but it works when i manually type it in either in the GUI expression box or directly into the xml.

1. Created variable to calculate conditional sorting

   ```
   <variable name="Data_Sort" class="java.lang.Double">
       <variableExpression><![CDATA[($P{Variance}=="Positive" ? $V{Vol_Diff}:(($P{Variance}=="Negative") ? $V{Vol_DiffInverse} :$V{Vol_AbsDiff}))]]>
       </variableExpression>
   </variable>
   ```
2. Created a Measure within the crosstab to access the sorting variable

   ```
   <measure name="DataSort_Measure" class="java.lang.Double">
       <measureExpression><![CDATA[$V{Data_Sort}]]></measureExpression>
   </measure>
   ```
3. Used the Measure variable in the orderby expression of the bucket of my rowgroup

   ```
   <rowGroup name="Well.WellName" width="150">
       <bucket order="Descending" class="java.lang.String">
           <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Well.WellName}]]></bucketExpression>
               <orderByExpression><![CDATA[$V{DataSort_Measure}]]>
               </orderByExpression>
           </bucket>
   ```